# Rendering Django template from withing template

Tags: python, django, templates

So, I have a number of objects I wish to render in a loop. I.E. Render each of the 5 latest posts on the home page. Each of these posts will be displayed differently whether or not the user is logged in.

I have a question: How would I go about making this distinction? I imagine having a template like this

```
{% if user.is_logged_in %}
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        post.render_long_form
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        post.render_short_form
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How can I make the functions `render_short_form` and `render_long_form` return the appropriate HTML snippits? I would like them to call other templates for rendering under the hood.

Thanks!

Comment: what's inside those render_long_for, etc? you can include a template in a loop

Comment: Why don't you make 2 templates, and just check `user.ise_logged_in()` in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't not use `{% include %}` tag?

```
{% if user.is_logged_in %}
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        {% include 'long_form.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for post in latest_posts %}
        {% include 'short_form.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Or, more DRY version:

```
{% for post in latest_posts %}
    {% if user.is_logged_in %}
        {% include 'long_form.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'short_form.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah, this sounds right. I guess I was just looking for the include keyword.

Comment: How does the `post` variable get used in the "long_form.html" file?

Comment: All variables from "parent" template are available in included template too.  So just use `{{ post }}` as usual.